# Name manager VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a code which basically loops through every sheet of the workbook (containing a huge number of sheets) and copies the text contained in some cells identified through the name manager. Basically, in every sheet there are 4 cells identified through the name manager as "Item_1","Item_2","Item_3","Item_4", as shown in the example.
[image]

This is a version of the code

```
for each anyWS in thisworkbook.worksheets
name=anyWS.Name
num_row=2
for num_row=2 To 4
if workbooks(xx).sheets(name).range("Item_"& num_row).value <> "" then
'the code does something...
else
end if
next
next
```

In some sheets, though, I have also a fifth item, so that I defined it "Item_5" through the name manager for that sheet. I edited this part of the above code: `for num_row=2 To 4` into `for num_row=2 To 5`, but it fails whenever a sheet doesn't have "Item_5" defined through the name manager, and the code displays an error: the object `workbooks(xx).sheets(name).range("Item_"& num_row).value` does not exist when `num_row=5`.
I tried the following:

1. define automatically "Item_5" through name manager for every sheet in the wb, but it doesn't work.
2. insert a statement `On error goto` where the code fails, but unsuccessfully, since when the loop is executed is "stuck" in the error. The code shouldn't stop. Simply, when it doesn't find the range named "Item_5", it should exit the for loop and go to the following sheet.
3. add a condition like `If not (workbooks(xx).sheets(name).range("Item_"& num_row).value) is nothing then`, to identify the cases when that name doesn't exist, but it doesn't work.

The third option seems the better to me, so I ask you if there is a way to identify the non-existing object defined through the name manager, in order to prevent that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Loop Through Named Cell Ranges

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopWorksheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For n = 1 To 5
            On Error Resume Next
                Set Cell = ws.Range("Item_" & n)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not Cell Is Nothing Then ' named cell exists
                If Len(CStr(Cell.Value)) > 0 Then ' named cell is not blank
                    'the code does something...
                    Debug.Print "The value of cell '" & Cell.Address(0, 0) _
                        & "' ('Item_" & n & "') in worksheet '" _
                        & ws.Name & "' is equal to '" & CStr(Cell.Value) & "'."
                Else ' named cell is blank
                    Debug.Print "The cell '" & Cell.Address(0, 0) _
                        & "' ('Item_" & n & "') in worksheet '" _
                        & ws.Name & "' is blank."
                End If
                Set Cell = Nothing
            Else ' named cell doesn't exist
                Debug.Print "The named cell '" & "Item_" & n _
                    & "' was not found in worksheet '" & ws.Name & "'."
            End If
        Next n
    Next ws
    
    MsgBox "Looped through worksheets.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

### Edit

- You could use a function and do something like the following (simplified).

```vb
Sub LoopWorksheetsUsingFunction()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    Dim RangeName As String
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For n = 1 To 5
            RangeName = "Item_" & n
            If NamedRangeExists(ws, RangeName) Then
                If ws.Range(RangeName).Value <> "" Then
                    ' do something
                End If
            End If
        Next n
    Next ws
    
End Sub

Function NamedRangeExists( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal RangeName As String) _
As Boolean
    Dim rg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rg = ws.Range(RangeName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    NamedRangeExists = Not rg Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: thank you, isn't there a faster way just to add a condition like point 3 in my list?

Comment: I don't understand how the On Error GoTo statements work...

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` defers error-trapping i.e. ignores all errors. It is active until the next `On Error` statement which is `On Error Goto 0` meaning stop error trapping. Now you cannot know if there was an error. Therefore you test if `Cell` is a reference i.e. is 'something' i.e. `Is Not Nothing`. If it is 'something`, then you can conclude there was no error (the name exists) and you can continue.